# Is it possible to define a function in <body> tag of <html> and call it form the <script> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to HTML and Javascript, and I have a strange doubt

Is it possible to define a function in "body" tag of html and call it form the "script" tag

Till now i am trying this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
   myFunction()
</script>
</head>

<body> 
function myFunction()
{
    alert("Hello World!");
}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "No". Not in a sane and idiomatic manner -- Extracting the text into a `<script>` or `eval`'ing it Would Work (TM), but *don't* do that. Just put JavaScript where it belongs.

Comment: I cant think of a reason why you want to do that

Comment: Thank you all for clearing the doubt...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No not possible. Browser only understands javascript within the `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

It will not work, try this,

```
<html>    
<body> 
<script>// don't miss script tags for javscript code
   function myFunction()
   {
       alert("Hello World!");
   }
</script>
<script>
   myFunction(); // call if you have defined function earlier
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
    alert("Hello World!");
}
myFunction();
</script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

or you can use body Onload.

Answer (score 0):

No U cant do it.....U should put js function within the script tag.....
you can do like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
   myFunction();
function myFunction()
{
    alert("Hello World!");
}
</script>
</head>

<body> 


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body> 
<script>
function myFunction()
{
    alert("Hello World!");
}
   myFunction()
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I agree with Rohan but just to check I removed the 2nd pair of script tags and called the function in the same script block as it was defined and it worked but this is not normally the way things are done and this is not normally the use of an embedded JavaScript (js)
Doing a little extra research to find the best/optimum place for embedded js appears to be at the bottom of a webpage before the /body (closing body) tag

Here's a link to Yahoo's "speed up your website" guide:
[Yahoo! Developer Network: Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Qlru.png)

and here's the text from the page that refers to embedded js:

> Put Scripts at the Bottom
>
> tag: javascript
>
> The problem caused by scripts is that they block parallel downloads. The HTTP/1.1 specification suggests that browsers download no more than two components in parallel per hostname. If you serve your images from multiple hostnames, you can get more than two downloads to occur in parallel. While a script is downloading, however, the browser won't start any other downloads, even on different hostnames.
>
> In some situations it's not easy to move scripts to the bottom. If, for example, the script uses document.write to insert part of the page's content, it can't be moved lower in the page. There might also be scoping issues. In many cases, there are ways to workaround these situations.
>
> An alternative suggestion that often comes up is to use deferred scripts. The DEFER attribute indicates that the script does not contain document.write, and is a clue to browsers that they can continue rendering. Unfortunately, Firefox doesn't support the DEFER attribute. In Internet Explorer, the script may be deferred, but not as much as desired. If a script can be deferred, it can also be moved to the bottom of the page. That will make your web pages load faster.

Also, if you go to the site and click the JavaScript tag you get a whole list of optimisations and tips - refer to the image!

[image: Screenshot of Yahoo Developer Network showing JavaScript optimisations]